# Creating alias for a pandera type: DataFrame with particular pandera schema

Tags: python-typing, pandera

I want to define a type to be a DataFrame with a particular pandera schema. However, when I lint this code:

```
from pandera.typing import DataFrame, Series


class MySchema(pa.SchemaModel):
    foo: Series[str]

MyDF = DataFrame[MySchema]

def myfun(df: MyDF) -> bool:
    return True
```

I get

```
myproject: myfile.py: note: In function "myfun":
myproject: myfile.py:10:15: error: Variable "myproject.myproject.myfile.MyDF" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]
```

I understand I can avoid this error by specifying `df: DataFrame[MySchema]` in the signature of `myfun` instead. Is there some way I can define the alias `MyDF` in a valid manner?